# Alternative to loading Facebook in iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, code-injection

I've been asked to build a website like the 2010 Skittles social media campaign some of you might rememeber (http://blog.thoughtpick.com/2010/02/learn-social-media-by-example-skittles-steals-the-social-media-rainbow.html).

My first thought was loading Facebook in an iFrame. Doesn't work, of course (X-Frame-options).
Next idea: injecting javascript to create the overlay: nope, not possible on Facebook, works on YouTube, though.
Last thing I can think of is rebuilding the layout of Facebook and catching the content via their API. Not really an easy solution.

Long story short: is there a smooth way to create an overlay on Facebook or load the site into the background of my website?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the page with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with **PHP** as an alternative to iframe.

```
$header = NULL;
$cookie = NULL;    
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies.txt'); //save cookies here
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com"); // you don't need that line; it's just the referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);;
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Also, with cURL you will be able to do modifications at the output of the page.

Comment: This actually works with Twitter, thank you.
Facebook and YouTube refuse to cooperate, though.

Comment: What's the output of Facebook by the way?

Comment: do I just have to echo $output? I don't get it.

Comment: I've just rechecked the code. Forgot to mentioned that you need to change URL for http://www.facebook.com and echo the $output. I edited my answer above. Copy - paste and test the code again.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But I will be forwarded to the actual page once i interact with the site, right? Is there a way completely keep the page in the background, so the overlay will be on top permanently?

Comment: I haven't found an answer to that yet on the net. I guess you need to create a $_GET for the url `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['url']);` and overwrite all types of different links like that. `$output = str_replace('http://','http://127.0.0.1/?url=http://',$output);`. You will need more replaces like that though to make it a perfect proxy.